# Flex direction property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Can somebody please explain why is it important to keep flex direction as column in this case? When you change it to row or row reverse, some portion of the image shrinks in width

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fbshqg0c/7/

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.text-img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1.25rem;
}

.width100 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <div class="text text-img-overlay">
      <div class="width100">
        <h1>500x320</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Changing `column` to `row` in your example has no effect.

Comment: It is actually visible in the JSFiddle I provided. I added background for body, so it is visible for changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the default value for `align-items` (alignment of secondary axis: Y when direction is row or X when direction is column) property is `stretch`, so when you use `flex-direction: column` the image is stretched on the X axis, but when you change it to `flex-direction: row` then it's stretched on the Y axis (vertical fit, but not horizontal).

You have to define `width: 100%` for the image.

Comment: Thank you! I got it

Answer (score 0):

I’m not completely sure what you mean because I didn’t see any difference but you don’t have a width value for the image, so probably this will fix your issue.

```
img {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: There is no problem actually. As long as I keep flex-direction in class left as column, everything works as planned. But when I change it to row, it appears to be a white space on the right side of the picture. The code snippet is not mine, so I am wondering why it is working like this. Is there any specific reason for such a behavior?